# Bootstrap's carousel indicators positioned at bottom of image when description is below

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My custom Bootstrap carousel has description below image. In this way  the problem arises which is the indicators when positioned vertically take in account descriptions height. Since description text varies I can't get indicators to stick to bottom of image.

So far as seen fixed spacing does not solve issue.

```
.carousel-indicators {
  margin-bottom:3rem;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/virsis12/5p6wm4sL/10/

How to calculate height for description so that appropriate spacing is applied to get indicators stay at bottom of image?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why dont you place your numbered ol somewhere else, it will be easier

Comment: Because this html structure is used in official docs.

Comment: Ok so try to move it outside, its not a crime to do something else that is not there in docs

Comment: in this case it will not do any good, because also photo can change its height, for example, carousel one of items is vertical photo. I sense there is no other way than to calculate descriptions height, but I dont know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check with these, add this small jQuery code in document.ready(). hope it will help you out.

```js
var newmargin = $('.carousel-item.active p').height();
$(".carousel-indicators").css("margin-bottom", newmargin); 
$('#carouselIndex').bind('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  var newmargin = $('.carousel-item.active p').height();
    $('.carousel-indicators').css("margin-bottom", newmargin);
});
```

```css
.carousel-item.active p { margin-bottom: 0px;}
.carousel-indicators li {
  background:orange;
  color:purple;
  height:auto;
  text-indent: 0;
  text-align:center;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div id="carouselIndex" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators carousel-indicators-numbers">
      <li data-target="#carouselIndex" data-slide-to="0" class="active">1</li>
      <li data-target="#carouselIndex" data-slide-to="1">2</li>
      <li data-target="#carouselIndex" data-slide-to="2">3</li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/10/18/17/42/season-4559795_1280.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption0">
          <p>This is very long description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2010/12/13/10/09/abstract-2384_1280.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption0">
          <p>2Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/12/09/00/16/smoke-69124_1280.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption0">
          <p>3Late night Dance ritual during summer solstice festival in Sigulda. 3Late night Dance ritual during summer solstice festival in Sigulda 3Late night Dance ritual during summer solstice festival in Sigulda 3Late night Dance ritual during summer solstice festival in Sigulda 3Late night Dance ritual during summer solstice festival in Sigulda</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```